# UIScrollView isn't scrolling to correct location

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with several objects in it which, when selected, I'd like them to come to the centre of the view. I am using the following code to do this.

```
CGRect frameToScrollTo;
frameToScrollTo.origin.x = (centerOfLabel - 150);
frameToScrollTo.origin.y = 0;
frameToScrollTo.size.width = 300;
frameToScrollTo.size.height = 44;

[self.monthsScroller scrollRectToVisible:frameToScrollTo animated:YES];
```

I have done tests to make sure the CGRect I'm creating is correct, but the UIScrollView always scrolls leaving part of the rectangle off screen. **This only happens when I have content insets applied**. My content insets change depending on the content so I can't do anything to remove these.

Can anyone please suggest a fix for this?

Thanks in advance.
Ricky.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out. I substituted `-scrollRectToVisible:animated:` with `-setContentOffset:animated:`.